# Properties of a Matrix with a Scalar Multiple Inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $C$ be an $n \times n$ invertible matrix. If the inverse of $C$ is $kC$, where $k$ is a positive real constant i.e. $C^{-1} = kC$. What are some properties that the matrix $C$ must necessarily possess under these conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $|A|$ refers to the determinant of the matrix and $adjA$ refers to adjoint of matrix.

$$C^{-1}=kC$$
$$|C^{-1}|=|kC|$$
$$\left|\dfrac{adjC}{|C|}\right|=k^n|C|$$
$$\dfrac{|adjC|}{|C|^n}=k^n|C|$$
$$\dfrac{|C|^{n-1}}{|C|^n}=k^n|C|$$
$$|C|^{n-1-n-1}=k^n$$
$$|C|=k^{-n/2}$$

Answer (score 1):

If $C$ is such a matrix, then $A=\sqrt{k}C$ is an involutory matrix, i.e., a matrix which is its own inverse. Indeed, we have
$$
A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}kC=\sqrt{k}C=A.
$$
Since then $A^2=I$, such a matrix $A$ is also called a square root of the identity matrix. Similarly, $C^2=\frac{1}{k}I$, so $C$ is a square root of a scalar multiple of the identity matrix. The eigenvalues of involutary matrices are always $1$ or $-1$. Some more properties are listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involutory_matrix).